# Trying to understand the renewbibmacro and DeclareFieldFormat construct

Tags: biblatex

I have migrated recently to `biblatex` and am trying to understand the many possibilities to tune and tweak the appearance of references in the bibliography. For example, for a work in a collection with a certain `volume` entry, I want to change the appearance of this `volume` in the bibliography.

I came along the `renewbibmacro` construction. Hence I added in the preamble of my document

```
\renewbibmacro*{volume}{%
    \printtext{VOLUMEMACRO}\space\printfield{volume}%
}%
```

This didn't result in anything, whereas using the `DeclareFieldFormat` did work:

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{volume}{\printtext{VOLUMEDECLARE} #1}
```

However, it didn't apply to the `volume` field in the `article`. When I used the `renewbibmacro` for `author`, it did work for an `article`:

```
\renewbibmacro*{author}{%
    \printtext{anon}%
}
```

I have searched this forum, as well as the `biblatex` manual, but could not find a concise overview on how to use these `renewbibmacro` and `DeclareFieldFormat` functions. Hence I am posting this myself. So I am interested to learn about the usage of this constructions, and what fields can and cannot be changed this way.

A `MWE` that shows that the `DeclareFieldFormat` for `volume` applies to the `collection` only, and that the `renewbibmacro` for `author` works:

```
\documentclass[10pt, english]{report}
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{abib.bib}
@article{some:article:1964,
    author   = "Mister Smart",
    title    = {A very difficult narrative of sub-atomic particles in the diary of Louis XIV},
    journal  = {Journal for Advanced Thinking},
    volume   = "41",
    number   = "3",
    year     = "1964",
    pages    = "307--323"
}    
@collection{collection:mass:histroical:vol1,
    options      = useeditor,
    title     = {Collections of the Massachusetts Historical Society},
    volume    = {i},
    series    = {third series},
    address   = {Boston},
    year      = 1896,
    sorttitle = {Collections of the Massachusetts Historical Society},
    shorthand = {Collections MHS Vol.~1},
    publisher = {Massachusetts Historical Society}
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{./abib.bib}

\DeclareFieldFormat{volume}{\printtext{VOLUMEDECLARE} #1}

%\newbibmacro*{volume}{%
%  \printtext{VOLUMEMACRO}\space\printfield{volume}%
%}%

\renewbibmacro*{author}{%
  \printtext{anon}%
}

\begin{document}
Test ~\textcite{some:article:1964} and~\textcite{collection:mass:histroical:vol1}.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have to differ between `bibmacros`, its `field formats` and `bibdrivers`.

- bibdrivers (file standard.bbx) are macros which print out the different entries, whereby each entry *type* (like book, article; except familiar ones) has its own macro.
- bibmacros are the biblatex *basic* macros which i.e. collect data for one specific topic: The printed `author` information maybe needs to be replaced by the `editor` information if no author is given etc.
- field formats work on a lower level. They are set for specific entry *fields* (author, title, year), while the bibmacros/bibdrivers patch them together. You can set field formats globally for all entry types or only for specific entry types, i.e. only emphasize the title field for the entry type book (just set it in square brackets).

To your MWE/code snippets:

```
\renewbibmacro*{volume}{%
    \printtext{VOLUMEMACRO}\space\printfield{volume}%
}%
```

That code snippet won't do anything since a) there never was a macro `volume` declared, and b) it wouldn't make much sense to declare one, since it only prints out information + a basic string.

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{volume}{\printtext{VOLUMEDECLARE} #1}
```

That is the right way to do it, since `volume` is a *field*...

**But**: If you want to have that format for all entry types, including the formats which already have been set, you have to overwrite all existing formats by used the starred version:

```
\DeclareFieldFormat*{volume}{\printtext{VOLUMEDECLARE} #1}
```

Following code snippet doesn't make sense, since it replaces all author information by your `anon` string:

```
\renewbibmacro*{author}{%
    \printtext{anon}%
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this detailed explanation. I was assuming wrongly that all entry fields (`author`, `volume`, `title`) in an entry type would have the same interface functions for making changes. Now I look further in the `biblatex` manual, the difference between a `list` entry as `author` and a `field` entry as `volume` become clear. My example for `author` was just an experiment to see if I could change the `author` field this way.